After UBUNTU 24.04.1 upgrade, unable to print to printer via WiFi
In late Sep. 2024 I upgraded to UBUNTU 24.04.1 LTS on my desktop computer.  When I re-started, I soon realized that I could no longer print (from Open Office Writer and Thunderbird email) to our Brother HL-2140 laser printer which I access by a WiFi link to a laptop in another room in the house.  The upgrade appears to have failed to transfer the WiFi links.  In ‘Settings’ → ‘Printers’ → ‘Printer Details’ → ‘Address’ = ‘null’.  All other entries in this window look OK. I am a Linux novice.  I need some guidance to recover my print capability with the appropriate ‘address’. Thanks.

What happened when you tried the IP address of the laptop?

I just had this problem. When I looked in Settings -> Printers at the printer's Printer Details, it said "Address (null)"; when I ran less /etc/cups/printers.conf and looked at the value of DeviceURI for the printer, it was cups-pdf:/. I ran lpinfo -v and saw the correct value for DeviceURI at the bottom, a long string, preceded by network , like dnssd://<escapedprintername>._ipp._tcp.local/cups?uuid=<someuuid>. I ran
sudo lpadmin -p <printername> -v dnssd://...etc.

to set the DeviceURI, but it didn't appear in /etc/cups/printers.conf until I restarted the cups service with sudo systemctl restart cups. Oddly, even though the right value is in printers.conf, and the printer now works, the Printer Details in Settings -> Printers still says "Address (null)".
